# Get MAC address from MySQL

Tags: mysql, mac-address

Is there any way to get one ore more of the mac addresses for a remote computer running MySQL?
The remote computer is on another subnet, and I can only use MySQL queries.

Comment: How should that work?

Comment: Are you looking for the MAC address of the MySQL server? Or the MAC address of a client? Either way, you cannot, this is a concern of the data link layer, that MySQL has no access to.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm not sure if it works. In MSSQL there were some workarounds to make it work, så there might be some way in MySQL too.

Comment: I'm looking for one ore more of the MAC:s of the MySQL server computer. Iäm not very expericned with MySQL, and I know it works in MSSQL, so hopefully there is a way for MySQL too

Answer (score 2):

If target machine is behind 3-rd level device or higher (router, for example), then, according to addresses encapsulation (TCP/IP stack and Ethernet address), you will not be able to access MAC-address of the client, since your server will receive packets from it's segment device (i.e. last router on the trace)

Comment: as i wrote in the question, teh remote computer is on another subnet, så I can't see it's MAC by looking directly at the connection

Comment: That's exactly what I meant in my answer. You can not get that address - you will receive MAC of your network segment's router instead (since Ethernet frames will contain it's address)

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for the MAC on the link level, I'm trying to get it througt MySQL queries. It's possible in MSSQL, so i have hope that it might be done in MySQL too

Comment: If MSSQL has access to it, it's not getting it from the link layer.

Comment: It probably gets it from the registry

Comment: How the registry is linked to network issues? If MSSQL provides that address (MAC I mean) - then it is an address of the last router on the trace. You can check that via `arp -a` command.

Comment: Okay, as I said before, and written in the question: I can ONLY use sql-queries to get the MAC. As I've also written, the remote server is NOT on the same subnet. MSSQL can give me the MAC addresses by quering the Windows registry, via sql queries. I need to know if there is any way to get the MAC via sql-queries on a MySQL server.

Answer (score 2):

You can get MySQL server MAC address from uuid:

```sql
select  uid                           AS uid
,       concat(
                substring(uid, 25,2)
        , ':',  substring(uid, 27,2)
        , ':',  substring(uid, 29,2)
        , ':',  substring(uid, 31,2)
        , ':',  substring(uid, 33,2)
        , ':',  substring(uid, 35,2)
        )                             AS uuid_to_mac
from    (select uuid() uid)           AS alias;
```

See http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2014/06/mysql-extracting-timstamp-and-mac.html